# Setup Scalate in Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, scalate

**Background**

I am working on a project using Play Framework 2.3.4.

I found the Twirl template engine great, but Scalate is even better. However, the instructions of setting up Scalate in Play Framework are outdated. I am not able to have it setup.

**Instructions Read**

I am aware of [this realted SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239245/integrating-scalate-into-play-2-0) and [this plugin](https://github.com/kryptt/play2-scalate-plugin) mentioned in the question. However, I found the build files in my project different from those mentioned in the plugin page.

In particular, I have got no *Build.scala* file.

**My Build Files**

*project/plugins.sbt*

```scala
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
name := """project-name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

Comment: That plugin looks very outdated and abandoned. It's only compiled for scala 2.9 and 2.10, just looking at the sonatype entries. I don't even see a 2.10 jar for play2-scalate-compiler. Your best bet is probably to fork it, update the dependencies, and try to get it to compile in Scala 2.11

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This would be beyond my skills of Scala and Play. I would stick to Twirl for now. Thanks.